# When do I top au gratin with seasoned breadcrumbs?

Tags: baking

Can I put seasoned breadcrumbs top of au gratin potatoes?

Answer (score 2):

You can if you want to. I have but not for years because that's not how I tend to cook potatoes these days.

There's no safety implication, and the flavours all work together so it's up to you. It's just a matter of choosing what seasonings will work well (for example I often use quite a bit of rosemary and black pepper in some potato dishes, but I'm not sure that's the best option here).

If the potatoes weren't par-cooked, you may find a thick layer of crumbs would overcook if left on for the full cooking time. Adding them for the end of cooking (10-20 minutes) te be a good idea in that case. If they do start to overcook, foil on top would slow that down, but should be removed a few minutes before the end of cooking, so the crumbs crisp up.